# Domain and set notation

Tags: notation

I looked through many threads and I found some different answers to this, but I want to know which one is the most 'proper'. Suppose I want to mark the domain of a function as the set of all real numbers ($\mathbb{R}$) except for all real numbers that satisfy $\frac{\pi}{2} + n\cdot\frac{5}{6}$ where $n$ is an integer. What is the best way to write this in math notation?

Comment: Use "setminus" notation.  $\mathbb R \setminus \{\frac \pi 2 + n\cdot \frac 56| n\in \mathbb Z\}$.

Comment: Oh.... or compliment.  *IF* it is understood you are assume $\mathbb R$ is your universal set and everything is in terms of $\mathbb R$ then $D = \{\frac \pi 2+n\cdot \frac 56|n\in \mathbb Z\}^c$ and..... you know... *don't* do that.  Just too much rope to have in proximity of your neck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Let $D$ be the set of all real number that are not of the form $\frac{\pi}{2} + n\cdot\frac{5}{6}$ for some integer $n$" would be usual. If you mean "how do I write it in some format with curly brackets at either end", then $$\left\{x \in \mathbb{R} : \not\exists n \in \mathbb{Z} : x = \frac{\pi}{2} + n \cdot \frac{5}{6}\right\}$$ or $$\mathbb{R} \setminus\left\{\frac{\pi}{2} + n\cdot\frac{5}{6} : n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$$ works, though neither is as clear as the version with more words, to me.

Answer (score 1):

Define $A=${$x_n|x_n=\frac{pi}{2}+\frac{5n}{6}$} and let $B=R-A$, $B$ is the set you want.